# iPhone SDK: How do I properly save user-inputted information into a .plist or other file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I've looked through the SDK documentation and through other questions that have been asked, and I am still a little confused on how exactly to do this.  I had been previously been working with the following code, though it does not give the desired result of a .plist file.  Besides mentioning the IBAction in the header files in this code in the .m file, is there anything else that needs to be added or anothe method I should be taking?  Thanks!

My Code:

```
- (IBAction)fedDog { 
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dogsFedDays.plist"];   
    NSMutableArray *dogsFedSave = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 100];  
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {  
        NSDictionary *myDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:  
                                                        date[i], @"string", 
                                                        fed[i], @"Yes", 
                                                        nil];  
        [dogsFedSave addObject:myDict];  
        [myDict release];  
    }  
    if (![dogsFedSave writeToFile:path atomically:YES])  
        NSLog(@"not successful in completing this task");  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that -writeToFile is returning NO so you're seeing your NSLog statement (correct me if I'm wrong). If that's the case, then the issue must be that some object in either your *date* array, or *fed* array is not any of the allowed object types for property lists which includes: NSString, NSData, NSArray, or NSDictionary. NSNulls are not allowed. From the docs for writeToFile:

> This method recursively validates that
>   all the contained objects are property
>   list objects before writing out the
>   file, and returns NO if all the
>   objects are not property list objects,
>   since the resultant file would not be
>   a valid property list.